# Symfony : ajax call works in prod environment, but not in dev environment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

In symfony 3, I am using ajax to retrieve some field based on the value of a first field as described in the documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

Here is my ajax code :

```
<script>
  var $groupeCompetence = $('#requete_prestataire_groupeCompetence');
// When sport gets selected ...
$groupeCompetence.change(function() {
  // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
  var data = {};
  data[$groupeCompetence.attr('name')] = $groupeCompetence.val();
  // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
  $.ajax({
    url : $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    success: function(html) {
      // Replace current position field ...
      $('#requete_prestataire_competence').replaceWith(
        // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
        $(html).find('#requete_prestataire_competence')
        );
            console.log("ok");
      // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.

    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {
      console.log(error));
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

And i got this error message :

> TypeError: tbody.rows.count is not a function
>       at startAjaxRequest ((index):173)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.open ((index):173)
>       at Object.send (jquery.js:9425)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9143)
>       at HTMLSelectElement. ((index):151)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5201)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5009)

What i dont understand, is the fact that all works in the prod environment (/web/) but not in dev environment (/web/app_dev.php/).

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: So, what you're saying is, the ajax call is completely unrelated to your problem? The error message tells you what function to look within and what line within that function... none of which are in your question currently.

Comment: Ok your are right : i clicked on the error, and noticed the problem was in the debug bar.
So a composer update fixed the problem.
It is a bug in symfony framework :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26460

Comment: This is an issue with Symfony `3.4.5` it was fixed in [`3.4.6`](https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-4-6-released). Effectively `tbody.rows.count()` needed to be replaced with `tbodies.rows.length`.